# How do I create composite components in Dart?

Tags: dart

How you create composite components in Dart?

I want to create some business forms with structured input field: labels, input text, a place for a field-specific error message? All of the forms will be created using a data driven approach so it needs to be done programmatically.

Is it as easy as subclassing DivElement and then adding those components with some styles applied?

I'v been using the dart editor to try and build some classes that will do this, but have not had much luck. All of the samples are quite unique and not as much related to business data entry, etc.

Answer (score 1):

DivElement is just a wrapper for a DOM div element, so you can't extend it directly.  However, new web tech is coming along nicely to help you out with this problem.  Check out Dart's [web components library](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-web-components).  There are also some community UI libraries that offer this feature.  You can find them [here](http://blog.dartwatch.com/p/community-dart-packages-and-examples.html).

Comment: You're being modest, John. Some him how you do it in Buckshot. :)

Comment: Yes I prefer in cases of general questions to remain somewhat neutral on SO. There are a few choices out there, which I provided.  It really comes down to an individual's choice on which framework they are most comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot subclass elements from the DOM... yet. (This is not a Dart issue, but an issue with web development in general.) However, a new system called "Web Components" is being built to address this (and other) issues.

Dart supports Web Components, and you can compile down Web Components into vanilla HTML/JavaScript/CSS and run across modern browsers. You can encapsulate styles, structure, and behavior with a Web Component. This gives you the basic nesting/compositing you are asking for.

Here's an example component for a form with behavior:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Copyright (c) 2012, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.
-->
<html lang="en">
<body>
<element name="x-todo-form" extends="div" constructor="FormComponent"
         apply-author-styles>
  <template>
    <!-- Note: <form> is to make "enter" work on Opera/IE. -->
    <form data-action="submit:addTodo">
      <input id="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" autofocus
             data-action="change:addTodo">
    </form>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart">
  import 'model.dart';
  import 'package:web_components/web_component.dart';

  class FormComponent extends WebComponent {
    void addTodo(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // don't submit the form
      if (_newTodo.value == '') return;
      app.todos.add(new Todo(_newTodo.value));
      _newTodo.value = '';
    }
  }
  </script>
</element>
</body>
</html>
```

You would use this custom element like this:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Copyright (c) 2012, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.
-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <link rel="components" href="newform.html">
  <title>dart - TodoMVC</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section id="todoapp">
    <header id="header">
      <h1 class='title'>todos</h1>
      <x-todo-form></x-todo-form>
    </header>
```

Note the `<link>` tag in the `<head>` section, which pulls in the component. And then notice the `<x-todo-form>` custom tag, which is the custom component you build in the first example.

Tada! Custom and composite elements! :)

The [open source Dart + Web Components project](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-web-components) is available. A [running example of TODOMVC with Dart + Web Components](http://dart-lang.github.com/dart-web-components/example/todomvc/index.html) is also available. Watch a [great video on Web Components](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2txPYQOWBtg).